# Setting HubSection ContentTemplate programmatically

Tags: wpf, templates

I'm developing an application for Windows 8 and am using Hubs and HubSections.
What I'm trying to do is create multiple HubSections depending on the JSON I fetch.
The problem I have is, when I try to set the new HubSection ContentTemplate the program crashes pointing to `global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();`

```
HubSection hs = new HubSection();
hs.ContentTemplate = this.Resources["canteenSectionDataTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
```

The thing is, if I set hs.ContentTemplate to the ContentTemplate of an already existing HubSection, it works fine, so I'm thinking the problem has to do with the template not being loaded yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't fix your problem, but it's worth noting that doing this is fairly bad practice for a number of reasons:

```
HubSection hs = new HubSection();
hs.ContentTemplate = this.Resources["canteenSectionDataTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
```

Instead of that, when using the `as` keyword, you should always check for `null` (unless you know without doubt that it will never be `null`, in which case you can just cast the value):

```
HubSection hs = new HubSection();
DataTemplate canteenSectionDataTemplate = this.Resources["canteenSectionDataTemplate"] 
    as DataTemplate;
if (canteenSectionDataTemplate != null) 
    hs.ContentTemplate = canteenSectionDataTemplate;
```

Apart from handling `null` errors, this code also enables you to check whether the `canteenSectionDataTemplate DataTemplate` *is* `null` or not.

So regarding your question, does the `canteenSectionDataTemplate DataTemplate` equal `null` or not? If it does, where is this code being called from? You may need to defer it to make it work.

Comment: I fixed the problem, it was a bug in my xaml data template declaration.
Either way, thanks for your answer!